# Procedural grid on a plane in 3d space in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl

I have a simple graphics program written in c++ that uses opengl for rendering. I have a plane that I draw at the origin and I want to add a procedural grid texture to it. In my current fragment shader I only do some lighting calculations:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 Normal;  
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec3 FragPos;  

uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 lightPos;  


void main()
{

    float ambientStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);  

    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    vec3 result = (((ambient + diffuse) * objectColor) * 0.5) ;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

My question is if modifying the fragment shader is the best way of having a procedural grid on my plane and if so how should I go about writing such a shader?

Comment: Since you already have the texcoord attribute, you need to create the texture, fill it with data, bind it to a texture unit, create a uniform sampler variable, set its value to point to appropriate texture unit, sample the texture and combine the result with your current code.

Unless you don't want to use a texture at all, in which case you can put the generation in the fragment shader directly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Thanks for the suggestion. I don't want to use textures but I am struggling with generating the grid in the fragment shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this will be to play around with trig functions. Since you are passing the texture coordinates already.

Let the color intensity be `max(cos(u), cos(v))`. That will give you a start. Then you should play around with the cos formula to get it exactly how you want it (i.e. multiply it by some coefficients and apply powers to it until it looks exactly how you need it).

Comment: Hi @Makogan. Thanks for the suggestion. what does 'u' and 'v' represent in the example code you provided above?

Comment: the u and v texture coordinates, i.e. the first and second component of the texture coord input into the shader

Comment: Thanks a lot, It is working. I will try to add the finished shader program when I am done.

Comment: Consider giving it a like too if it solved your problem : ).